# Does a sequence of derivatives takes on its limiting value?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, derivatives

I'm working on the following question:

> Assume $f$ is continuous on an interval containing zero and
>   differentiable for all $x \neq 0$. If $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f'(x) = L$, show $f'(0)$ exists and equals $L$.

My strategy:

I use the continuity of $f$ to produce an open neighborhood around $0$. In this neighborhood I can find a symmetric closed interval around zero - say $[-\frac{h}{2},\frac{h}{2}]$. By mean value theorem I get $f'(c_1)$ on the interval $(-\frac{h}{2},\frac{h}{2})$. I can use the above fact to create a closed interval containing $c_1$ and $0$ - it will be strictly contained in $(-\frac{h}{2},\frac{h}{2})$. Iterating this procedure will yield a sequence of derivatives $(f'(c_i))$. I'm given that this sequence's limit is $L$. Now I'm stuck.

1. How do I pass to the limit to show $f'(0)$ takes the value $L$? I don't have any information about the continuity of the derivative.
2. I know my open interval contains a closed interval that's smaller. What fact am I using here though?

Comment: I think this will work if you take the left-hand and right-hand derivatives instead.

Comment: Use mean value theorem directly to write $(f(x) - f(0))/x=f'(c_x)$ and as $x\to 0$ we have $c_x\to 0$ (why?) so that RHS tends to $L$ and therefore LHS does the same and thereby we obtain desired result.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I'm still a bit confused. I can see how the LHS and RHS will converge to $L$. How do I know this $L = f'(0)$? Consider the function that takes $1$ for all $y \neq 0$ and $2$ at $y = 0$. The LHS and RHS limits agree but they don't take on the value of the function at the point. Your procedure creates a sequence of derivatives at the left and right, but they don't necessarily give me the value at $f'(0)$

Comment: @saulspatz same comments as above

Comment: o wait, I see, this sequence of derivatives is also a sequence of difference quotients with one end point at $f(0)$ -- this allows us to produce left hand side and right hand side derivatives

Comment: There is no need to consider left and right derivatives. Just take $x\to 0$ and note that $c_x\to 0$. And if you note carefully the limit of LHS is by definition $f'(0)$ so you get the equality $f'(0)=L$.